# Is anyone familiar with the notation $\sigma|_M$?

Tags: notation, field-theory

I am looking at Ian Stewart's Galois Theory 4th Edition, and unsure about what the notation means. Here's the theorem that the notation is first seen,

> Suppose $L:K$ is a finite normal extension and $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$. Let $\tau$ be any $K$-monomorphism $M \to L$. Then there exists a $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ such that $\sigma|_M=\tau$.

Now, I first thought $\sigma(M)=\tau$ is what he means. But bizarrely, he uses the notation $\tau(M)$ elsewhere for what seems to mean $M$ evaluated by $\tau$. So basically, the set of elements of $M$ that are mapped by $\tau$.
It actually doesn't make sense to mean $\sigma(M)=\tau$ since $\tau$ is not a set but a map. $\sigma(M)$ must give me another set of elements, something like a field or whatnot.

So I guess it's different, but I can't think of any other possible meaning. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means $\sigma$ restricted to $M$. That is, $\sigma(x)=\tau(x)$ for all $x\in M$.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you very much!

Comment: "Restricted" means that $\sigma|_M$ is the function with domain $M$ that agrees with $\sigma$ on $M$.